# Recursive call to makefile does not update object files

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with a recursive call to itself. When I first run make, the object files are created and linked just fine. But when I modify a source file and run make again, the objects are not recreated (make says the target is up to date). I need to run `make clean` and then run make. Here is simplified version of my makefile which I think includes all relevant information:

```
PCC = mpicc

#Locations
OBJDIR = ./objects

#Compiler and linker flags
FLAGS = -g -lm

#Object files
SHAREDOBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,shared1.o shared2.o)
SPECIFICOBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,specific1.o specific2.o)

#How to compile and link
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(PCC) -c $*.c $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$*.o

PROGNAME:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) EXTRA_FLAGS="$(FLAGS)" PROGNAME_TARGET

PROGNAME_TARGET: $(SHAREDOBJS) $(SPECIFICOBJS)
    $(PCC) $(SHAREDOBJS) $(SPECIFICOBJS) $(EXTRA_FLAGS) -o PROGNAME
```

So running `make PROGNAME` the first time compiles just fine. But the second returns `make: "PROGNAME" is up to date.`

It appears to me that the recursive call is never made. For example, if I add an `echo` right before the call to make, nothing is displayed in `stdout`.

Why is this happening? Why are the timestamps on the source files not checked in the recursive call? I don't understand why the recursion breaks the dependency on the source files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question is, WHY do you have such a recursive call?  Why not just do everything in the same invocation?  Adding the recursion is what's causing your problem.  If you really, truly want the recursion then you need to mark `PROGNAME` as `.PHONY` so that the recursion will happen every time.

Comment: @MadScientist: I want the source files to be compiled with a different set of flags depending upon the target. So I have another target, say `PROGNAME2:` where `EXTRA_FLAGS` is set to something different. But it looks like using target-specific variables might be a cleaner way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target `PROGNAME` has no prerequisites.

The first time you `make PROGNAME`, Make sees that there is no such file, so it executes the rule.

The second time (after you modify `shared1.o`), Make sees that `PROGNAME` already exists, and that the target has no prerequisites, so it sees no need to rebuild the target. It doesn't know that `PROGNAME` depends on `shared1.o`, because you didn't tell it.

There's more than one way to solve this problem. I suggest you do away with the recursion entirely and use a [target-specific variable value](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
PROGNAME: EXTRA_FLAGS="$(FLAGS)"
PROGNAME: PROGNAME_TARGET
```

(Your target names could be improved, but that can wait.)

Comment: Yep, that is exactly the problem! I can't believe I overlooked this. Changing the output filename to something different from the first target name easily fixes this. But your comment about target specific variables is a much cleaner approach. Thanks a lot!