# A Makefile does not update objects

Tags: makefile, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

Even though I'm following the [GNU make online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) step by step, a problem on makefiles still puzzles me.
I'm working on a very simple makefile:

```
OBJ = main.o funz.o

main :  $(OBJ)
    gfortran -g -o main $(OBJ)

funz.o : funz.for
    gfortran -g -c funz.for
main.o : main.for
    gfortran -g -c main.for

clean : 
    rm main.o funz.o
```

According to what I've learned on makefiles, `funz.for` is a prerequisite for `funz.o`. Everytime I change the source code `funz.for`, `make` should update `funz.o` and link it to `main` again. But whenever I launch `make` I get told that `main` is up to date and does not recognize the changes in `funz.for`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199133/recursive-call-to-makefile-does-not-update-object-files) I've found is related to the same problem but doesn't solve mine, since I think my prerequisites are posed correctly.
Am I missing something?

**UPDATE 1**

As asked by Etan Reisner, here is the output of `make -rRd`:

```
This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `main'.
  Considering target file `main.o'.
    Considering target file `main.for'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `main.for'.
     No implicit rule found for `main.for'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `main.for'.
    No need to remake target `main.for'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `main.o'.
   Prerequisite `main.for' is older than target `main.o'.
  No need to remake target `main.o'.
  Considering target file `funz.o'.
    Considering target file `funz.for'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `funz.for'.
     No implicit rule found for `funz.for'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `funz.for'.
    No need to remake target `funz.for'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `funz.o'.
   Prerequisite `funz.for' is older than target `funz.o'.
  No need to remake target `funz.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main'.
 Prerequisite `main.o' is older than target `main'.
 Prerequisite `funz.o' is older than target `main'.
No need to remake target `main'.
make: `main' is up to date.
```

And here's the output of `stat funz.o funz.for; touch funz.for; stat funz.o funz.for; make -rRd`

```
  File: `funz.o'
  Size: 3176            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 58197897    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  505/ lorenzo)   Gid: (  505/ lorenzo)
Access: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.200737262 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.192737262 -0500
Change: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.192737262 -0500
  File: `funz.for'
  Size: 129             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 58196947    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  505/ lorenzo)   Gid: (  505/ lorenzo)
Access: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.183737262 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.174737262 -0500
Change: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.174737262 -0500
  File: `funz.o'
  Size: 3176            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 58197897    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  505/ lorenzo)   Gid: (  505/ lorenzo)
Access: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.200737262 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.192737262 -0500
Change: 2015-11-19 16:23:06.192737262 -0500
  File: `funz.for'
  Size: 129             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 58196947    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  505/ lorenzo)   Gid: (  505/ lorenzo)
Access: 2015-11-19 16:23:47.478737151 -0500
Modify: 2015-11-19 16:23:47.478737151 -0500
Change: 2015-11-19 16:23:47.478737151 -0500
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `main'.
  Considering target file `main.o'.
    Considering target file `main.for'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `main.for'.
     No implicit rule found for `main.for'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `main.for'.
    No need to remake target `main.for'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `main.o'.
   Prerequisite `main.for' is older than target `main.o'.
  No need to remake target `main.o'.
  Considering target file `funz.o'.
    Considering target file `funz.for'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `funz.for'.
     No implicit rule found for `funz.for'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `funz.for'.
    No need to remake target `funz.for'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `funz.o'.
   Prerequisite `funz.for' is newer than target `funz.o'.
  Must remake target `funz.o'.
gfortran -g -c funz.for
Putting child 0x0197ea80 (funz.o) PID 69914 on the chain.
Live child 0x0197ea80 (funz.o) PID 69914
Reaping winning child 0x0197ea80 PID 69914
Removing child 0x0197ea80 PID 69914 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file `funz.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main'.
 Prerequisite `main.o' is older than target `main'.
 Prerequisite `funz.o' is newer than target `main'.
Must remake target `main'.
gfortran -g -o main main.o funz.o
Putting child 0x019830d0 (main) PID 69917 on the chain.
Live child 0x019830d0 (main) PID 69917
Reaping winning child 0x019830d0 PID 69917
Removing child 0x019830d0 PID 69917 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `main'.
```

**UPDATE 2**

I noticed something really strange (which I always overlooked): I'm editing my source files through the WinSCP client, and it seems like, after updating my source files, the "last modified" time goes wrong. As you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOwKO.png), even if I modified `funz.for` a few minutes ago, the shown time of its last change is unexplicably 6 hours before my actual time (it's almost 5 P.M. here).

Comment: Can you show the output from `make -rRd`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: sure! I have updated the question with the information you asked.

Comment: `Prerequisite \`funz.for' is older than target \`funz.o'.` make thinks your source file is older than your object file. Did you make a change to it?

Comment: @EtanReisner: yes, I made a change to `funz.for` and saved the source file: but nonetheless, `make` see it as older than `funz.o` and feels that there is no need to update `main`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE that might be compiling for you automatically or something? What's the output from `stat funz.o funz.for; touch funz.for; stat funz.o funz.for; make -rRd`? (To test if things are generally working correctly.)

Comment: @EtanReisner: i've updated the question!

Comment: @EtanReisner: I noticed something strange with my files. I updated the question with a picture of my WinSCP client.

Comment: Is there a timezone difference on your local machine and the server? Are you connecting via sftp or scp?

Comment: @EtanReisner: my local machine and the server are just a room away from each other. ;) I'm connecting with WinSCP, so yes, I suppose I'm updating files via SFTP or SCP. I'm definitely no expert on this, though. Is it possible that my local computer has a different time than the remote?

Comment: It is. What are the times and timezones on each machine? And sftp and scp are different (and may matter here) so which are you actually using? (Check the connection information in winscp or try to start a new one and see what the selection dropdown says.)

Comment: @EtanReisner: typing `date` the following time appears: `gio 19 nov 2015, 17.29.43, EST`. EST zone is UTC -5; but I'm in Italy, whose time zone is UTC +1. This may explain the 6 hour gap. So many thing I didn't know of my working station, it seems! I'm working with the SCP protocol: I checked it at the bottom right corner of my WinSCP panel.

Comment: So your server has very much the wrong timezone? You should probably fix that.

Comment: @EtanReisner: It seems so. I will fix it right away. Thank you so much for your time and sorry for bothering you for such a silly thing. How can I choose the best answer? Can I write it myself or it's up to you?

Comment: I voted to close as "cannot reproduce" personally. You can certainly get it fixed and then write an answer up and accept it if you prefer that instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner: ok, that's not a problem. I thought every question had to be closed with some kind of formalized answer. Thank you again!

Comment: They should be answered or closed/deleted, yes. Being left hanging is undesirable. So, your choice, but I would either submit and accept your own answer or vote to agree with my "cannot reproduce" vote (which should close it automatically I believe).

Comment: @EtanReisner: I can't find any voting option... maybe I do not have enough reputation? I may write and accept my own answer later then.

Comment: Hm... yeah, looks like you might not have enough to cast a close vote on your own questions (not sure I understand why that would work that way though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the remote computer I am working with had a different time than the local computer, hence the different timestamps and the makefile not working.